# Alljoyn takes too long to discover a device

Tags: android, alljoyn

I have two critical issues:

1) My devices cannot find each other using the ICE. Is ICE being shut down? A couple of weeks ago **ICE was enabling devices to find each other very quickly**!

2) Why is alljoyn taking so long to discover another device in my home's local wireless network? Both testing devices are connected to a wifi router that allows communication between them. I believe **if alljoyn was acting a little bit more actively** the devices would be discovered much more quickly. Right now it gets two or more minutes to find the other device!

Current setup is very simple:

- No multipoint
- Single service
- Single interface
- Have enabled all transports *except wifi direct and bluetooth*

Thank you! I am looking forward of solving it

Answer (score 1):

From within alljoyn forums it is revealed that the current release alljoyn version for android works without ICE.

The forum administrator replied that the alljoyn core team is currently preparing a more reliable better ICE for device discoverability.

Until then the proposed solution is to build alljoyn from source by changing all occurences of `rdvs.alljoyn.org` to `connect.alljoyn.org` beforehand

I cannot say that it worked for myself since I stumbled upon issues while trying to complete the step "compile android from source"